# JDBC Connection Pool SSL Error PKIX building failed

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, glassfish, glassfish-4

This is using the latest Glassfish (4.1), the latest Postgres Driver (9.3-1102 JDBC 41) against Postgres 9.4, and the latest Java (1.8.0_31-b13).

This is also using a commercial CA certificate, I have checked the CA root is present in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts.  For good measure I have also added the intermediate certificate.

I have also verified Root and intermediate is in the glassfish domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks

The error message I am receiving is :

> An error has occured.  Ping Connection Pool failed for XXX.  Connection could not be allocated because: SSL error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed sun.security.provider.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

The Postgresql log shows the following :

```
LOG:  could not accept SSL connection: sslv3 alert certificate unknown
```

The Glassfish server.log doesn't show anything more than the above error.

If I set

> sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory

Then of course ping works fine.  But this is obviously completely and utterly unacceptable for production purposes where protection against MITM attacks is without question mandatory !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to answer my own question, I was doing everything right.  The only thing I missed was checking Postgres SSL certs were being read from the correct file (/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf ).

I can now Ping successfully